# Укажите предложение с лексической ошибкой

Tags: лексика

1. Наша передача посвящена ветеранам.
2. Пресса позитивно оценивает результаты переговоров.
3. Все это стало для меня неожиданным сюрпризом.

Answer (score 1):

Всё это стало для меня сюрпризом. Всё это стало для меня неожиданностью. Сюрприз всегда неожиданен!

Comment: сюрприз, наверное, неожидан?

Comment: да!...........